# Images in cloud storage suddenly can't be served through images.get_serving_url(blob_key)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, blobstore

I have a web app on Google App Engine with images saved in cloud storage (gs) and served through images.get_serving_url(blob_key).

It is working fine last week and today I found the following error:

```
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~best-dish/1.387902702294290826/models/menu.py", line 54, in get_image_url
    return images.get_serving_url(self.image_blob_key, 0)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/images/__init__.py", line 1794, in get_serving_url
    return rpc.get_result()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 613, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/images/__init__.py", line 1892, in get_serving_url_hook
    raise _ToImagesError(e, readable_blob_key)
```

Note that the same URL and image was working perfectly last week so I guess something happened between last week and today? Is there anyone experiencing the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be fixed by Google and everything is back to normal.